# Tripods and Tripod adapters for pistol grips

Tags: location-recording, tripod, gear, pistol-grip

Does anyone out there have a preferred tripod for mounting your pistol grips? I think I've seen photos of people using something akin to a small/cheap camera tripod before, but that could have been some overly-optimistic induced delusion.

I'm also curious about [these devices](http://www.trewaudio.com/store/product.php?productid=55&cat=38&page=1), if anyone has used them before and can provide their thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried 'em all, and I keep coming back to lightweight tripods over mic stands, primarily for use on uneven terrain, since the legs can be independently set (and I'm not about to schlep a "Rocky Mountain Leg" c-stand into the field!). The Joby Gorillapod works brilliantly on small recorders like the H2. Small units like the Slik Sprint Pro (with ball heads) are good, lightweight solutions for even stereo mid-side rigs in zeppelins; stable in calm conditions and weighs less than 1kg. I also graft mic boom arms onto lightweight light stands for more height variability and a minimum length when packed (article on that practice [here](http://www.noisejockey.net/blog/2009/07/07/lightweight-mic-stands-in-the-field/)).

Since most tripods are outfitted with 1/4-20 screws, I use step-down bushings in my pistol grips' 3/8" threads. I also keep a set of 5/8-1/4 and 5/8-3/8 adapters in the bag so that I can adapt any tripod to any mic stand to any tripod. I have 2 each of the appropriate bushings and adapters in my audio grip kit.

Comment: Have you used any of those spider-tripods, with the flexible legs you can wrap around just about anything?

Answer (score 1):

I bought a similar thread adapter to mount our pistol grip to our studio mic stand. Works great.

Comment: @Steve - cool. that answers that question. now to find out if there are any tripods that work straight out of the box. we're trying to eliminate unnecessary adaptors from our location kits.

Answer (score 0):

When I go out in the field, I am usually taking small mic stands, especially if I am recording ambiances.  I don't necessarily need the height, and you can get away with uneven terrain if you don't have a really tall stand.  Something you might mic and guitar cabinet with, but without the boom.